# Check the network Connectivity is stable since last one minute

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-networking

I want to check the connection stability for my project.

So kindly help to get time in minute from last Connectivity change i.e.(Connected to notConnected).

Comment: use event bus to check

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />    
<receiver android:name=".YOURRECEIVER">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add this to your `Manifest` and then in `YOURRECEIVER` (Or whatever the name), you will listen to this event `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` which will be triggered in `onReceive`.

Now you can get time like `System.currentTimeInMillis()` or do whatever you want when the connectivity changes state.

So you can save the time with `SharedPreference` and read from that when you want to access last time.